# Prevent multiple fast clicks from triggering API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, sequelize.js

For my project a instagram-clone, I have a like and dislike button. If there are no likes or dislikes from the current logged in user, both will show black. If I like the post the like will show blue, and then when I click dislike, it switches from like to dislike, from blue to red. And clicking which ever is activated like/dislike it will unlike or undislike. The problem that arises, is that when you click super fast it somehow breaks through and adds multiple likes, when each user should only be able to add one like or one dislike.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: For multiple fast clicks you can implement rate limiting by using `Debouncing` or `Throttling`, it is fairly easy to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate limiting example using `Debouncing`. If the user clicks fast multiple times only the last click will register. You can change the delay time as per your requirements.

```js
const debounce = (fn, delay) => {
  let t = null;
  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(() => {
      fn(...args);
    }, delay);
  }
};

let handleLike = () => {
  console.log("Like Clicked");
};

handleLike = debounce(handleLike, 1000);

const btn = document.querySelector("#like");
btn.addEventListener("click", handleLike);
```

```html
<button id="like">
  Like
</button>
```

Comment: Wow thanks so much, I had figured something with setTimeout would somehow be the way of doing this but was not too sure. Very helpful explanation